# Magento how to show discounted price with custom option product

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento 1.9 have product custom option's price and i want to show discounted price.
Suppose product's Color option is Red and its price is $100, I want to show it with discount(20%) price which should be $80. Please let me know in which file i have to write my script.

Comment: Is any body there, Who know about this.  Thank you

Comment: no body is there ? Strange

Comment: I solved it my self

Comment: Hi @pavan sharma, How you solved this? Can you please share us info. Thanks