# Add special price for custom options - Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I would like to show special price for Custom Options product.
Is it possible with Magento 1.9? Thanks in advance.

Reference Link:
[Magento how to show discounted price with custom option product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785762/magento-how-to-show-discounted-price-with-custom-option-product)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic; it has also been posted on [magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241981/add-special-price-for-custom-options-magento-1-9) (otherwise I'd suggest it might be better being migrated)

Comment: Could you link some relevant code to start us off with? So we can make a relevant example for you :)